# How to make toggle select in recyclerView in Android?

Tags: android

I have an app which contains `recyclerView` with some data. The scenario is something like that; when I click one item its image change and what I want when I click another item, click item image will change and previous clicked item image gets normal. I have implemented code but the problem with my code is that when I was clicking other items previous clicked item image remains the same.

code:-

```
public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
    currentSelectedIndex = pos;
    if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
        selectedItems.delete(pos);
        animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
    } else {
        selectedItems.put(pos, true);
        animationItemsIndex.put(pos, true);
        animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
    }
    notifyItemChanged(pos);
}
private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

// array used to perform multiple animation at once
private SparseBooleanArray animationItemsIndex;
private boolean reverseAllAnimations = false;
```

Comment: Is it multiSelection or SingleSelection ?

Comment: it is due to you only notify changed at `pos` index. That position is current selected index. You have to notify changed at previous selected index to make it get normal

Comment: Since you are changing two different elements of your array and notfying for only one. `notifyDataSetChanged` might work instead of `notifyItemChanged(pos);`

Answer (score 0):

This goes into `YourViewHolderClass`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    imageView.setSelected(true);

    if (previousSelection != null && imageView != previousSelection)
        previousSelection.setSelected(false);

    previousSelection = imageView;

    if (mClickListener != null)
        mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
}
```

Also, you have to define an interface inside the Adapter

```
 // allows clicks events to be caught
public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

// parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Basically you will just save the previous view selected.

**EDIT:** I used a `selector` on the item of the `RecyclerView` as background

**EDIT:** add this line to the view from `recyclerview item` that you want to get changed upon selection

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_material_type_selector"
```

**ic_material_type_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
    android:drawable="<!-- drawable / color for selected state -->"/>
    <item android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="<!-- drawable / color for unselected state -->"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
currentSelectedIndex = -1;
public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
if(currentSelectedIndex!=-1) {
    //Previous Item is unselected
}
    currentSelectedIndex = pos;
    if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
        // Current item is selected
    } else {
        // Current item is unselected
    }
    notifyItemChanged(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class SomeRecyclerAdapter extends Adapter {

```
    private int mLastClickedPosition = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

....

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SomeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final boolean activatedState = mLastClickedPosition == position;
        holder.itemView.setActivated(activatedState);// this is only example, you can use "activatedState" in different ways
    }

    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        final int lastClickedPosition = mLastClickedPosition;
        mLastClickedPosition = position;

        if (lastClickedPosition >= 0) {
            notifyItemChanged(lastClickedPosition);
        }
        if (mLastClickedPosition >= 0) {
            notifyItemChanged(mLastClickedPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

From here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ef280c79c7c3f4aae1406c818149f8c

Answer (score 0):

```
final int currentClickedPosition = -1;

under button click.....under onBindViewHolder method....

final int lastClickedPosition = currentClickedPosition ;
currentClickedPosition = position;

//do your stuff here............

if(lastClickedPosition != currentClickedPosition ){
    notifyItemChanged(lastClickedPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage which item is currently selected with `isSelected` boolean from the data class.

**RecyclerView Item Model**

```
data class OptionModel(
    var title: String? = "",
    var isSelected: Boolean = false, //control single selected view
    var logo: Int? = 0
)
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter > `onBindViewHolder(..,..)`**

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
   toggleSelection(position)
 }
```

The general idea is to know which position is selected and toggle it's boolean to true, other item's boolean to false.

**function toggleSelection**

```
 fun toggleSelection(position: Int) {
     var currentSelectIndex = position
     listData.forEachIndexed { index, paymentOption ->
         paymentOption.isSelected = index == currentSelectIndex
     }
     notifyDataSetChanged()
 }
```

The same value can be used further in the code and also helps updating the UI by `notifyDataSetChanged()`